# Golang: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, multipartform-data

When uploading a file to my go app, I encounter a panic.

```
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
 /Users/bob/Projects/go/src/github.com/zenazn/goji/web/middleware/recoverer.go:24 (0xbaf5b)
    func.006: debug.PrintStack()
 /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 (0x1043d)
    panic: runtime·newstackcall(d->fn, (byte*)d->args, d->siz);
 /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:552 (0x10eed)
    panicstring: runtime·panic(err);
 /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/os_darwin.c:454 (0xfb8e)
    sigpanic: runtime·panicstring("invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference");
 /usr/local/go/src/pkg/mime/multipart/multipart.go:223 (0xb6801)
    (*Reader).NextPart: if r.currentPart != nil {
 /Users/bob/Projects/go/src/github.com/app/controllers/company_sheet_controller.go:32 (0x2ee18)
    NewCompanySheet: part, err := mr.NextPart()
 /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1235 (0x44f00)
    HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP: f(w, r)
 /Users/bob/Projects/go/src/github.com/zenazn/goji/web/router.go:113 (0x6bc0a)
```

This method handles an upload from a multipart form, extracting the file contents and boundary data.  The `r.FormFile` method on request is used to set file and header.  And in order to pull the additional data from the post, I use `r.MultipartReader`.  From the error description I see `r` is already declared as `ParseMultipartForm` when using `r.FormFile`.  When executing the function with the different request methods individually, I receive no errors. `r.FormFile` and `r.MultipartReader` work fine isolated.  Am I unable to mix the two request methods?

```
func Upload(r *http.Request) {
  file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
  ErrorCheck(err)

  mr, err := r.MultipartReader()
  ErrorCheck(err)
  part, err := mr.NextPart()
  ErrorCheck(err)

  var b bytes.Buffer
  io.CopyN(&b, part, int64(1<<20))
  fmt.Println(b.String())
  defer file.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling FormFile() at the beginning of your function.

This calls ParseMultipartForm() (see [Request.FormFile](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile)) which populates the MultipartForm field of your [http.Request](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request).

Now the [documentation for MultipartReader()](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.MultipartReader) states that you should use MultipartReader() **instead** of ParseMultipartForm() if you want to process the data as stream.

Looking at the [source](http://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=10494:10556#L286) MultipartReader() returns an error if the MultipartForm field was already set.

So to answer your question: No, you can't use both functions for the same request.

Also your

```
defer file.Close()
```

should be right after you checked for an error from FormFile(), otherwise the file won't be closed before Garbage Collection, when your function panics.

Comment: Here is the code example I found very useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/29197782/4932661