# How to decode this nested json with Golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to decode nested json as part of a request containing a file and data.

The data looks like this

```
{data: {"date_required":null}}
```

I did not originally include the full error because I had forgotten to log it.

```
2023/11/17 23:40:35 error in decoding request body data
2023/11/17 23:40:35 invalid character '.' looking for beginning of value
```

I believe that this error may be as a result of the form data not being JSON but don't know how to fix it. My Flutter code looks to me like it sent valid JSON. The Content-Type is `multipart/form-data` and this may be what is causing the error. I believe the file upload part of my code requires this Content-Type.

The request is coming from my Flutter client with the following code:

```
final multipartFile =
    http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', bytes, filename: file?.name);

final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(user.fileUrl));

request.files.add(multipartFile);

request.headers.addAll(headers);

String dateRequiredStr = dateRequired != null
    ? jsonEncode({'date_required': dateRequired})
    : jsonEncode({'date_required': null});

request.fields['data'] = dateRequiredStr;
```

In my go API I am doing this.

model (edited as per answer below):

```
type FileRequiredDate struct {
    DateRequired pgtype.Date `json:"date_required"`
}

type FileRequiredDateData struct {
    Data FileRequiredDate `json:"data"`
}
```

code:

```
func (rs *appResource) uploadTranscriptAudioFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

start := time.Now()

const maxUploadSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024 // 500 Mb

var requiredByDate FileRequiredDateData

decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)

err := decoder.Decode(&requiredByDate)

if err != nil {
    log.Println("error in decoding request body data")
    log.Println(err.Error())
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")

if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

defer file.Close()

fileSize := handler.Size

if fileSize > maxUploadSize {
    http.Error(w, "FILE_TOO_BIG", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

fileName := handler.Filename
```

`httputil.DumpRequest` -> Content-Type: multipart/form-data

EDIT: Following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181995/how-do-you-parse-both-a-file-and-json-data-out-of-one-http-request-with-go) I edited the code like this:

```
mr, err := r.MultipartReader()

if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

for {
    part, err := mr.NextPart()

    // This is OK, no more parts
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    // Some error
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("multipart reader other error")
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    log.Println(part.FormName())

    if part.FormName() == "data" {

        log.Println("multipart reader found multipart form name data")

        decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)

        err = decoder.Decode(&requiredByDate)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error in decoding request body data")
            log.Println(err.Error())
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }
}

    if part.FormName() == "file" {

        file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")  <-- error here

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error getting form file")
            log.Println(err.Error())
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        defer file.Close()

        guid := xid.New()

        userId := getUserFromJWT(r)

        user, err := getUser(rs, int64(userId))

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("user not found")
            log.Println(err.Error())
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusInternalServerError), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        err = uploadToMinio(rs, file, fileSize, fileName, guid.String(), userId)


----
```

which gives me this output:

```
2023/11/17 23:23:30 data
2023/11/17 23:23:30 file
```

EDIT:

I fixed the immediate issue by using `decoder := json.NewDecoder(part)` instead of `decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)`

Now I am getting `error getting form file`. It seems like I should be using part somehow but there is no file property for part. r.Body is no longer available since I added form data to the mulitpart request. That looks like a different question.

Comment: `FileRequiredDateData`'s structure does not match the JSON's structure. That type has two separate "sibling" fields; not one nested in the other, like the JSON has.

Comment: I don't know how to represent that json string in a model.

Comment: Please provide more code specific to the request handling.

Comment: There is no more code specific to the request handling unless you want the file handling code which I know works.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like you haven't exposed an API for your client code to request. If this is all the code your server contains, then you should refer to some go API tutorials, e.g. https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/web-service-gin

Comment: There is no path error. The file upload part works fine. The issue is restricted to parsing the request post body.

Comment: Are you sending a valid JSON request body? The updated error seems to indicate that the handler is not receiving a valid JSON

Comment: The data posted by the client has not changed. It may be that the presence pof the file attachment is interfering with parsing the body. I can't figure out how to print only this part of the request body. I updated my question with more API code.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was downvoted. I have many years experience in researching and writing questions. The problem here is hugely important to me and I intend to provide the maximum bounty.

Comment: You are trying to decode multipart/form-data as JSON. Use [Request.MultipartReader](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.MultipartReader) or [Request.MultipartForm](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.MultipartForm) with [Request.ParseMultipartForm](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm), then decode only the JSON part.

Comment: I found this and will try it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181995/how-do-you-parse-both-a-file-and-json-data-out-of-one-http-request-with-go

Comment: There never was a 404 error, the error returned is 400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this isn't going to solve the 404 issue (please update your question with the request handler code), your struct doesn't appear to match what you are sending. You can do something like this to fix that:

```golang
type FileRequiredDate struct {
    DateRequired pgtype.Date `json:"date_required"`
}

type FileRequiredDateData struct {
    Data FileRequiredDate `json:"data"`
}
```

That should decode the request body as expected.

As for the 404, you should double check the request path and method your client code is sending matches your server request handler path and method.

Comment: I used your code but I get a parse error as described in my updated question. The original 404 error was hard coded by me to indicate a parse error.

Comment: @markhorrocks The code in the question has hardcoded `StatusBadRequest`, which is `400` and not `404`. You claims and your code don't align very well, which makes it more difficult to suggest an accurate solution. Also in your updated question you do not "describe" the error; we don't know whether you truly mean a "parse error" (which would indicate that the incoming JSON is invalid), or whether you mean "decoding error", which may suggest that the JSON values still don't match the target type.

Comment: @markhorrocks given that you've failed to provide adequate information about the issues you are having, I can only guess at what the problem might be: One reason could be that `null` and `pgtype.Date` don't go well together, sometime a pointer (i.e. `*pgtype.Date`) can fix that problem. Another reason might simply be that `pgtype.Date` doesn't support the JSON data format sent in the JSON, in which case you should not use `pgtype.Date` but instead a type that can handle the incoming JSON value.

Comment: I have provided every line of the relevant code. I have hundreds of `pgtype.Date` in my models which work fine with null data in posts from Flutter.  I'm unaware that there is even a differecne between a decode and a json parse error. That's why this site exists.

Comment: @markhorrocks the code is irrelevant at this point; show what the exact error message is, what's the output from `log.Println(err.Error())`?

Comment: @markhorrocks to confirm that the request body contains the data that you expect it to contain you can dump the request before trying to decode it. Try `dump, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)` and then `log.Println("request dump:", string(dump))`. For more details about the util func, see: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil@go1.21.3#DumpRequest

Comment: @markhorrocks please update your question to include the output of `log.Println(err.Error())` and of `log.Println("request dump:", string(dump))`.

Comment: My apologies. I had forgotten to log the fiull error and so didn't include it. This issue is at the very end of 2 years work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255965/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-markhorrocks).

Comment: I tried using `httpUtil.DumpRequest` but the presence of an image file in the request made this unproductive for me.

Comment: The error is 400, not 404.