# How to get multipart.File from multipart.Part without saving to disk in Go?

Tags: go

In my go API I have a function which previously worked fine by extracting the`multipart.File` from `r.Body` like this

```
file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")
```

I use the `multipart.File` to upload to an s3 API using the minio client like this

```
err = uploadToMinio(rs, file, fileSize, fileName, guid.String(), userId)
```

Now I have added additional form data and can't seem to user r.Body for this anymore. I am getting "error getting form file" as indicated in the code below.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181995/how-do-you-parse-both-a-file-and-json-data-out-of-one-http-request-with-go) I have implemented a `MultipartReader` to get the form data from multipart.Part.

part has no `multipart.File` so I need to get to that without writing the part to disk and reading it again if possible.

Here is my code

```
var err error

start := time.Now()

const maxUploadSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024 // 500 Mb

var requiredByDate FileRequiredDateData

mr, err := r.MultipartReader()

if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

for {
    part, err := mr.NextPart()

    // This is OK, no more parts
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    // Some error
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("multipart reader other error")
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    log.Println(part.FormName())

    if part.FormName() == "data" {

        log.Println("multipart reader found multipart form name data")

        decoder := json.NewDecoder(part)

        err = decoder.Decode(&requiredByDate)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error in decoding request body data")
            log.Println(err.Error())
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

    if part.FormName() == "file" {

        file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file") <-- error getting form file here

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error getting form file")
            log.Println(err.Error())
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        defer file.Close()

----

    err = uploadToMinio(rs, file, fileSize, fileName, guid.String(), userId)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusInternalServerError), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already streaming the parts of the form, you cannot call `FormFile` now, you have to read the file yourself. Use `part.Read` to read the bytes of the file, or copy it, etc. Note that `part` implements `io.Reader`, so you can read from it as if you're reading a file.

Comment: My minio upload requires a multipart.File. How can I derive that from part.Read?

Comment: @markhorrocks  If `uploadToMinio` only calls `Read` on the file, then change the function to take an `io.Reader` instead of a `multipart.File`.  If `uploadToMinio` seeks on the file, then you may need to download the file to memory or disk.  It may be helpful if you edit the question to show the code for `uploadToMinio`.